# WCF endpoint address, default still available after specifying an address

Tags: wcf, endpoints

These are my endpoints

---

endpoint name="rest" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
          behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" 
          contract="IActionService"

endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"

---

which makes the service available at /here

when I change the address to [say] 'rest'

---

endpoint name="rest" address="**rest**" binding="webHttpBinding" 
          behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" 
          contract="IActionService"
endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"

---

the service is then available at /rest/here.

which makes sense, but it is also available from the original address of /here

I thought that the original address would not exist as I have set the address to 'rest'.

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What defines your base address of **`/here`** ? Do you have a `<host>` section with `<baseAddress>` entries in it?

What do you mean by "still available" from the original address? Requests going there still return valid results?? Have you reset IIS after this config change??

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am hosting the service in a website/iis. My explanation is not good. Yeah mean to say that the service still works from the original address, which seems strange. Is it some default that must/can be removed somehow?

Comment: OK, I think I have found my answer. I had my 'rest' endpoint and I was using [WebGet(UriTemplate ... )] attribute. WCF is nice but a bit of a struggle.